# Forcing HTTPS in Laravel causes Login Redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the following code in `AppServiceProvider` to force HTTPS when in production on a Laravel 5.8 project:

```
if(App::environment() === 'production') {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

My understanding of `forceScheme()` was that it didn't do any redirecting, it just swapped out `http` for `https` at the beginning of links.

I'm monitoring page loads via Laravel Telescope and for every Request, it also makes the following additional requests:

[image]

So 2 questions. Is my understanding of `forceScheme() incorrect? What is the best way of achieving HTTPS without reloading on Laravel 5.8?

Comment: You may also try .htaccess for this.

Comment: htacces or your hosting provider ma offer force https.. less work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with `.htaccess`. Open your public folder and put the following code into the .htacess file:

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

**Another solution:**

```php
if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
    $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doing that breaks Laravel Telescope because assets are still being passed through as http

Comment: The second solution solve this problem for me. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, behaviour is still there with the 2nd solution, strange!

Comment: What's actually happening?

Comment: Same issue as before. You load a page, it also seems to load requests each time for Login and site.webmanifest. I've tested the local version of the app and it doesn't do this. Only in production.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your **AppserviceProvider** or create **middleware** for this

```
if($this->app->environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Or use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```